# が at the end of the sentence

Tags: grammar, particle-が

In the following sentence:

> 切符を買いたいんですが
> I would like to buy a ticket.

What is the usage of が?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Native usage of けど](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/28458/native-usage-of-%e3%81%91%e3%81%a9)

Comment: @user3856370  While I agree that the essence of the answer is there, I'm not satisfied with the answers in this related question because it doesn't really make enough of a strong connection between けど and が.

Comment: Can I use けど instead of が in the sentence above?

Comment: @QuinceBlossom Yes, they are pretty much interchangeable in this case.

Comment: @ajsmart Not sure I understand your objection. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: @user3856370 Sure,  The answers in the linked question don't establish the relationship/similarities between けど and が.  So for a user new to the language, they would see this duplicate as unrelated because it isn't clear that けど can replace が in this case.  We see が addressed twice in the answers and once in the comments, but it doesn't really establish/elaborate on the connection.

Comment: @ajsmart I see what you mean. That didn't occur to me. Although, in combination with your supporting comments above I still feel it can be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @user3856370 Lets just hope they read the comments then.  I'll abstain from voting to allow others to weigh in on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/2088/9831  See also: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/57358/9831

Comment: Does this answer your question? [けど at the end of the sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2086/%e3%81%91%e3%81%a9-at-the-end-of-the-sentence)

Comment: Yes, somehow it does.

Answer (score 1):

> *26.4.1.4* Clause1 **ga**. (  .  .  .  ) in unfinished sentences
>
> Sentences where S2 is left unsaid (implied) are commonly used, especially
> for introducing requests, to test the listener’s reaction, but also to imply
> that realization of S2 is not possible or realistic.
>
> a)  ちょっとすみません**が**......。
>
> Chotto sumimasen **ga**......
>
> Excuse me.
>
> b)  ちょっとお伺いしたいんです**が**。
>
> Chotto o-ukagai shitai n desu **ga**.
>
> Could I ask you something?
>
> c)  覚えていないんです**が**......。
>
> Oboete inai n desu **ga**......
>
> I don’t remember.

Source: Japanese: A Comprehensive Grammar. Routledge (2013)

and

https://itazuraneko.neocities.org/grammar/donnatoki/ngyoudonnatoki.html#%E3%82%93%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8C

If you want an explanation in Japanese

Comment: Snapping and uploading screenshots is really not an ideal practice and should be discouraged. It is not searchable and may be hard to see on some devices. Since this is a fairly straightforward question that calls for a straightforward answer, I suggest you summarize that paragraph and type out their examples in a block quote. Btw, good job locating that passage. It's right on.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. Good catch. I'll do it properly from now on :)